# Issue accessing folder in Tridion 2011 SP1

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

After upgrade from Tridion 5.3 to Tridion 2011 SP1, we found that we are not able to access Flash folder from Tridion GUI.  Whenever we click on that folder it throws below error and do not display any content, in fact there are more than 100 flash files in that folder.

```
(80040000) ' ' is an unexpected token. The expected token is ';'. Line 1, position 50.Unable to get list of SDL Tridion Content Manager items.
System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception)
System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String,String[])
System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowUnexpectedToken(String,String)
System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowUnexpectedToken(Int32,String,String)
System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.HandleEntityReference(Boolean,EntityExpandType,Int32&)
System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseAttributeValueSlow(Int32,Char,NodeData)
System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseAttributes()System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElement()
System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadNode(Boolean)System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadDocSequence(XmlDocument)
System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument,XmlReader,Boolean)
System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader)
System.Xml.XmlDocument.LoadXml(String)
Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.ContentManagement.ItemDataMapper.CreateBinaryContentData(IdentifiableObjectData,FieldDictionary)
Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.ContentManagement.ComponentDataMapper.ReadPost(TcmUri,FieldDictionary)
Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.IdentifiableObjectDataMapper.Read(TcmUri,IDataRecord,IDictionary`2)
Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.ContentManagement.OrganizationalItemDataMapper.GetListItemsPost(IDataReader,TcmUri,OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData)
Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.ContentManagement.OrganizationalItemDataMapper.Tridion.ContentManager.Data.ContentManagement.IOrganizationalItemDataMapper.GetListItems(TcmUri,OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData)
Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.OrganizationalItem.GetListItemsData(OrganizationalItemItemsFilter)
Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.OrganizationalItem.GetListItemsStream(OrganizationalItemItemsFilter)
Tridion.ContentManager.BLFacade.ContentManagement.OrganizationalItemFacade.GetListItemsXml(UserContext,String,ListFilter,ListColumnFilter)
Tridion.ContentManager.BLFacade.ContentManagement.OrganizationalItemFacade.GetListData(UserContext,String,EnumListKind,ListColumnFilter,String)Folder.GetListItems
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky one, probably best served by SDL Customer Support. However, if you have access to the server directly, I would try pasting the URI of the folder in question into Internet Explorer (this must be on the CMS server itself). This should give you the XML representation of the folder, and may give you some clues. Perhaps you can post that XML in your question also.

Answer (score 0):

We encountered this error when we upgraded from SDL Tridion 2009 to SDL Tridion 2011.
The resolution that worked for us was removing the Linked Schema from the Folder, refreshing and then re-attaching the linked schema.